# Has Yau's conjecture been proved?

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, conjectures, minimal-surfaces

The Wikipedia article about Yau's conjecture says "The conjecture has recently been claimed by Kei Irie, Fernando Codá Marques, and André Neves in the generic case." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yau%27s_conjecture

Does this mean they claim it has been proved for **all** cases? Has it been proved once and for all?

Comment: Read https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10752

Comment: @Coolwater I am a layman, hehe.

Comment: So your question is really about what "in the generic case" means?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. And additional details would be nice too.

Comment: The conjecture is only proven for generic metrics, genericity is the sense of the Baire category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their theorem is that for every compact 3-dimensional manifold $M$ in the space $Riem(M)$ (consisting of all Riemannian metrics on $M$ equipped with $C^\infty$ topology), there exists a countable union of nowhere dense closed subsets:
$$
C= \bigcup_{n\in {\mathbb N}} C_n\subset Riem(M)
$$
such that for every metric $g\in U:=Riem(M) \setminus C$, Yau's conjecture holds. The set $U$ can be regarded as a set of "generic" Riemannian metrics on $M$. (For instance, it is dense in $Riem(M)$.)

As an aside, their proof depends on the earlier result by Liokumovich, Marques and Neves proving a "nonlinear version of Weyl's law" (conjectured by Gromov) for minimal surfaces.

I am not sure though how much the terminology I used makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in the generic case. But note that, more recently, a student of Marques has proven the conjecture for all metrics. See

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.08816.pdf

One can even update the Wikipedia article now!